# Execute function on second click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, calendar

I have a calendar button that on click opens up a date picker and places the date into an input text box.  What I want to happen, is have a second text box auto-fill with the date 30 days into the future.  What I am having trouble with is getting this to work with jquery.

HTML:

```
<tr>
<td align = "center">Entry Date From:  <input id="ENTRYDATEFROM" name="ENTRYDATEFROM" type="text" maxLength="10" size="12" value="">
<img height="20"src="calendarsrc" id="entrySrc"></td>
<td align = "center">Entry Date To:   <input id="ENTRYDATETO" name="ENTRYDATETO" type="text" maxLength="10" size="12" value="">
<img height="20"src="calendarsrc" id="entrySrc2"></td>
</tr>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#entrySrc").click(function(){
     gAnytime.fPopCalendar(document.myform.ENTRYDATEFROM);
  });

  $("#entrySrc2").click(function(){
     gAnytime.fPopCalendar(document.myform.ENTRYDATETO);
  });

  //Tried this but had no success
  //$(document).on("change", "#entrySrc", populate);


});

function populate(){
 var q = $("#ENTRYDATEFROM");
 var dateTo    = new Date(q.val()); 
 var newDate   = new Date(dateTo.setDate(dateTo.getDate() + 30));
 var formatted = padNumber(newDate.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' + padNumber(newDate.getUTCDate()) + '-' + newDate.getUTCFullYear();
 $("#ENTRYDATETO").val(formatted);
}

function padNumber(number) {
  var string  = '' + number;
  string      = string.length < 2 ? '0' + string : string;
  return string;
}
```

This is what my GUI looks like before anything is clicked:

[image]

This is what happens when I click the #entrySrc calendar button located to the right of the input text box

[image]

I can then click on any date that I wish within that calendar box.  This will populate the input text box to the left of it.

How can I execute my populate function on/against that second click located within the calendar box?

Comment: I have even gone as far as doing a mouseup and mousedown....but still nothing :(

Comment: So how could I go about combating my problem?

Comment: I am trying to work out what your click handlers are trying to accomplish... Can you please provide your HTML (with your code) in a JSFiddle?

Comment: I am working with a gigantic web project that has hundreds of classes and javascript files...I'm not sure how I would go about providing an example of it.  Maybe I can reword the question

Comment: Can you at least provide links to the plugin you are using... A Google  search for `fPopCalendar` results in some of the worst website I have ever seen! :)

Comment: I have edited the question so that it makes a little more sense and provides more information

Comment: Without know more about `fPopCalendar`, this is guesswork. Normally you would listen for a suitable event from the calendar control ("e.g. "change" as jonas.ninja suggested) but we need to see the API/documentation. Is there a website for `fPopCalendar` you can point to?

Comment: I believe this is the website that references it:http://www.calendarxp.net/

Comment: Also, it looks like the package we are using is _dtpicker

Comment: `calendarxp.net` has awful documentation. Not sure why they bother to trademark "eXtremely Perfect", when its perfection is *somewhat hidden behind a rubbish website*. :) Start with http://calendarxp.net/tutorials/flat/tutorials/PluginsSDK.htm and the `fOnChange` event handler. No idea if that is a global function, a property of some namespace or an options you pass. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a very simple solution to this: simply fire the populate() method when #entrySrc *changes*.

```
$(document).on("change", "#entrySrc", populate);
```

or one of these alternatives:

```
$("#entrySrc").on("change", populate);
$("#entrySrc").change(populate);
```

note you're passing `populate`, not `populate()`.

Comment: Receiving no results, the #entrySrc is actually the calendar button image.  I also tried: 

    `$("#ENTRYDATEFROM").on("change", populate());`

Which called populate whenever the input text box changes, but nothing there as well

Comment: I'd like to make sure you're not using cached code in your tests. Are you hard-refreshing? Ctrl+F5 on Windows, Cmd+Shift+R on Mac. Testing against stale code is something I always have to watch out for at work :)

Comment: OH, I see the problem. You can't call `populate()` like that, you have to omit the parentheses. I didn't make a typo.

Comment: Yes I am refreshing after every change made

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, I misspoke: one is a *shortcut* according to the API. The other is indeed a delegated event, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the very poor documentation here: http://calendarxp.net/tutorials/flat/tutorials/PluginsSDK.htm I would guess you need to do the following:

Open your `plugins.js` file, which is apparently where to hook into a load of global functions (this control is sooooooo old).

Put your code into the `fOnChange` template (which I gather will be a nearly empty function):

```
///////////// Calendar Onchange Handler ////////////////////////////
// It's triggered whenever the calendar gets changed to y(ear),m(onth),d(ay)
// d = 0 means the calendar is about to switch to the month of (y,m); 
// d > 0 means a specific date [y,m,d] is about to be selected.
// e is a reference to the triggering event object
// Return a true value will cancel the change action.
// NOTE: DO NOT define this handler unless you really need to use it.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function fOnChange(y,m,d,e) {
  .... put your code here ....
return false; // return true to cancel the change.
}
```

What you put in there should be something of practical use. I would suggest generating a custom event like this:

```
function fOnChange(y,m,d,e) {
    var $e = $(e.target); // (or e.originalTarget or whatever you can find with a debugger!)
    $e.trigger("calchange");
    return false; // return true to cancel the change.
}
```

This will require that jQuery is included before their js file.

In your code, listen for it like this *for all calendars*:

```
$(document).on('calchange', populate);
```